# Header image positioned center whilest remaining its dimensions with no horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

Im going to try to explain this as best i can. I have a header image that is 2560x400 px. But for example the image could be  (ex.2 4000x400px). I want to be able to position the image in so it is in the middle of the screen, so taking ex.2 in the middle of a given screen would be the 2000 pixle of the header image.

I have gotten on okay, managing to remove the horizontal scrolling but i need some help if anyone can help me :).

html

```
<img class="pop" src="My image 2560x400" alt="">
```

css

```
.pop { 
    width: 2560px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.pop {
    width: 2560px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, its appreciated. I tried using that styling and it positioned the image from the left hand side of the page, not centeral.

Comment: It works fine for me. Please check styling of the others elements around this.

Comment: I have looked, and looked xD Could it be something to do with the body tag. I actually didn't code the whole page it was a pre-made tumblr theme. my tumblr is http://antineutrinoo.tumblr.com/ the header is the tree image, that is with your styling used. I realise im being abit needy, so you dont have to answer if you dont have the time :p

Comment: Yes, It can be because <img> tag must be inside the <body> tag. And may be body tag is having width less than the <img> or float to the left.